# How to extract numbers and letters from a string Imacros

Tags: imacros

For example if I extracted this string 1234hrt-13hfydsfn-12 how could I extract the data so that i could extract the numbers and letters only?

Answer (score 0):

With this code, for example:

```
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/\W/g, '');")
```